# How to catch Control-V in C# app?

Tags: c#, message, keyevent

I've tried to override WndProc, but no message show up on paste event.

Then I tried to create custom filter and using method PreFilterMessage I was able to catch message with value 257 (KEYUP event), but that's not enough...

Answer (score 18):

Use:

```
 protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
 {
      if (e.KeyCode == Keys.V && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
      {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello world");
      }
      base.OnKeyDown(e);
  }
```

Make sure your form KeyPreview = true.

Comment: FYI - Thats not me asking the question

Comment: First you'd need to implement such feature (using context menu strip i guess). You'd have full control over it anyway

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by:

- Intercepting the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in KeyDown (or KeyUp) of your form
- Creating a menu in your form that contains a Paste option that has the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> shortcut (this would maybe be better since you will have users looking for the options)
- Intercepting the KEYDOWN message like you described in the question and checking whether <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is pressed at that time (I think this is the hardest of all 3).

Personally I would go for using a menu option.